# Cannot center header and section inside wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have my header and section inside my wrapper and inside the header and section is an image. I'm just trying do one simple thing - take the parent wrapper and it's child elements and center them on the page. No matter what I do, it stays flushed to the left corner of the screen. Below: Html and CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Katie Simone Music</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" a href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <img src="images/header1.png">
            </header>
            <section>
                <img src="images/pic.png">
            </section>
       </div>
</body>
</html>

 #wrapper{
    max-width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
 }
```

Comment: Have you verified that the stylesheet is being loaded?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/) Link?

Comment: The `#wrapper` css which you showed in code, is it part of `main.css` file?

Comment: Rishabh Shah - yes, it is.

Comment: divy3993 - https://jsfiddle.net/w87pq5Lv/1/

Answer (score 0):

```css
 #wrapper{
    max-width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Katie Simone Music</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" a href="css/main.css">
    </head>



<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <img src="images/header1.png">
    </header>

    <section>
        <img src="images/pic.png">
    </section>
    </div>
</body>






</html>
```

add `text-align:center` to the #wrapper style

```
#wrapper{
    max-width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add also this:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #wrapper{
  max-width:940px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
  text-align:center;
 }
```

[Working DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/t6opk51p/)

Comment: It's working now. Thanks.  #wrapper{
  max-width:940px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
  text-align:center;
 }